# Query optimization (multiple joins)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-performance

I would like to find a way to improve a query but it seems i've done it all. Let me give you some details.

**Below is my query :**

```
SELECT 
    `u`.`id` AS `id`,
    `p`.`lastname` AS `lastname`,
    `p`.`firstname` AS `firstname`,
    COALESCE(`r`.`value`, 0) AS `rvalue`,
    SUM(`rat`.`category` = 'A') AS `count_a`,
    SUM(`rat`.`category` = 'B') AS `count_b`,
    SUM(`rat`.`category` = 'C') AS `count_c`
FROM
    `user` `u`
    JOIN `user_customer` `uc` ON (`u`.`id` = `uc`.`user_id`)
    JOIN `profile` `p` ON (`p`.`id` = `u`.`profile_id`)
    JOIN `ad` FORCE INDEX (fk_ad_customer_idx) ON (`uc`.`customer_id` = `ad`.`customer_id`)
    JOIN `ac` ON (`ac`.`id` = `ad`.`ac_id`)
    JOIN `a` ON (`a`.`id` = `ac`.`a_id`)
    JOIN `rat` ON (`rat`.`code` = `a`.`rat_code`)
    LEFT JOIN `r` ON (`r`.`id` = `u`.`r_id`)
GROUP BY `u`.`id`
;
```

*Note : Some table and column names are voluntarily hidden.*

**Now let me give you some volumetric data :**

```
user => 6534 rows
user_customer => 12 923 rows
profile => 6511 rows
ad => 320 868 rows
ac => 4505 rows
a => 536 rows
rat => 6 rows
r => 3400 rows
```

**And finally, my execution plan :**

[image]

**My query does currently run in around 1.3 to 1.7 seconds which is slow enough to annoy users of my application of course ... Also fyi result set is composed of 165 rows.**

**Is there a way I can improve this ?**

Thanks.

**EDIT 1 (answer to Rick James below) :**
*What are the speed and EXPLAIN when you don't use FORCE INDEX?*

Surprisingly it gets faster when i don't use FORCE INDEX. To be honest, i don't really remember why i've done that change. I've probably found better results in terms of performance with it during one of my various tries and didn't remove it since.

When i don't use FORCE INDEX, it uses an other index ad_customer_ac_id_blocked_idx(customer_id, ac_id, blocked) and times are around 1.1 sec.
I don't really get it because fk_ad_customer_idx(customer_id) is the same when we talk about index on customer_id.

Comment: You may review your database design to ensure that the data aren't inefficiently cluttered. If not, don't worry I think it's a good time for data retrieval.

Comment: How many rows does it return for a whole 1.3 seconds?

Comment: it returns 165 rows !

Comment: What are the speed and EXPLAIN when you don't use `FORCE INDEX`?

Comment: Let me answer this in an edit above.

Comment: Mmmh seems a fairly straightforward query on the first looks of it ... Did you try to tweak the engine? (join) buffers, memory allocation  etc ?

Comment: No I didn't, it may be a solution.

Comment: ad_customer_ac_id_blocked_idx is a compound index over 3 columns. The value of the first (important) two are known, so this index will perform better than an index on only the first column.

Comment: From the information provided currently, it may not be possible to improve this query. Altering schema and/or tuning buffers could help. Could you list the indexes on all the involved tables? It may be possible to add additional information to the query so that it can use more efficient indexes.

Example: I have a table with hundreds of millions of rows. This table has many indexes, but the most efficient one is usually a 4-part compound index. The first part of this index is environment. In our DB, i_env is always 1, but if I omit this from the query, that index cannot be used.

Comment: You have demonstrated why `FORCE INDEX` is _usually_ becomes a bad idea.

Comment: you can select all the records in subquery which have all the joins then select all the rows from the subquery and apply sum to the rows selected from that subquery, theory is in one step just select the records from joins then apply calculations in the second select.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get rid of `FORCE INDEX`.  Even if it helped yesterday; it may hurt tomorrow.

Some of these indexes may be beneficial.  (It is hard to predict; so simply add them all.)

```
a:  (rat_code, id)
rat:  (code, category)
ac:  (a_id, id)
ad:  (ac_id, customer_id)
ad:  (customer_id, ac_id)
uc:  (customer_id, user_id)
uc:  (user_id, customer_id)
u:  (profile_id, r_id, id)
```

(This assumes that `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of each table.  Note that none have `id` first.)  Most of the above are "covering".

Another approach that sometimes helps:  Gather the `SUMs` before joining to any unnecessary table.  But is seems that `p` is the only table not involved in getting from `u` (the target of `GROUP BY`) to `r` and `rat` (used in aggregates).  It would look something like:

```
SELECT ..., firstname, lastname
    FROM ( everything as above except for `p` ) AS most
    JOIN `profile` `p`  ON (`p`.`id` = most.`profile_id`)
    GROUP BY most.id
```

This avoids hauling around firstname and lastname while doing most of the joins and the `GROUP BY`.

When doing `JOINs` and `GROUP BY`, be sure to sanity check the aggregates.  Your `COUNTs` and `SUMs` *may* be larger than they should be.

Comment: In "( everything as above except for `p` )", is this a subquery "select sum(...), sum(...)" ?

Comment: @Gosfly - The idea is to do all the aggregate as quickly and easily as is practical, _then_ reach for (`JOIN`) other columns needed.

Comment: You can (probably) GROUP BY `uc.user_id` instead of `u.id`. Then `user`, `profile` and `r` can be joined outside the aggregation subquery. I though doubt that it will improve much (if at all), since those joins don't increase the number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need to `tick`.`everyTableAndColumn` in your queries, nor result columns, aliases, etc.  The `tick` marks are used primarily when you are in conflict with a reserved work so the parser knows you are referring to a specific column... like having a table with a COLUMN named "JOIN", but JOIN is part of SQL command... see the confusion it would cause.  Helps clean readability too.

Next, and this is just personal preference and can help you and others following behind you on data and their relationships.  I show the join as indented from where it is coming from.  As you can see below, I see the chain on how do I get from the User (u alias) to the rat alias table... You get there only by going 5 levels deep, and I put the first table on the left-side of the join (coming from table) then = the table joining TO right-side of join.

Now, that I can see the relationships, I would suggest the following.  Make COVERING indexes on your tables that have the criteria, and id/value where appropriate.  This way the query gets as best it needs, the data from the index page vs having to go to the raw data.  So here are suggestions for indexes.

```
table             index
user_customer     ( user_id, customer_id )   -- dont know what your fk_ad_customer_idx parts are)
ad                ( customer_id, ac_id )
ac                ( id, a_id )
a                 (id, rat_code )
rat               ( code, category )
```

Reformatted query for readability and seeing relationships between the tables

```
SELECT 
        u.id,
        p.lastname,
        p.firstname,
        COALESCE(r.value, 0) AS rvalue,
        SUM(rat.category = 'A') AS count_a,
        SUM(rat.category = 'B') AS count_b,
        SUM(rat.category = 'C') AS count_c
    FROM
        user u
            JOIN user_customer uc
                ON u.id = uc.user_id
                JOIN ad FORCE INDEX (fk_ad_customer_idx) 
                    ON uc.customer_id = ad.customer_id
                    JOIN ac 
                        ON ad.ac_id = ac.id
                        JOIN a 
                            ON ac.a_id = a.id
                            JOIN rat 
                                ON a.rat_code = rat.code
            JOIN profile p
                ON u.profile_id = p.id
            LEFT JOIN r
                ON u.r_id = r.id
    GROUP BY 
        u.id
```